# Event not executing inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding content in the `iframe dynamically` and that content are binded with an event using `.live() function` :

```
           <body>
            <div id="container">
               <iframe id="if" src="something"></iframe>
            </div>

            <script>
             /* binding event */
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $("p").live("mouseover", function() { /* do something */ });
             });

             /* appending content */
              $("#if").contents().find("#someid").append("<p></p>");                  
            </script>
           </body>
```

The `p tag` added successfully but the event is not executed on mouseover. Whats the problem?

**Note** : I can`t add the binding event script inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your live binding is only for the main document not for the iframe. Did you try following?

With jQuery 1.4 and above use [jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$("#if").ready(function() {
    $("#if").contents().delegate("p", "mouseover", function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

With jQuery 1.7 and above use [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#if").ready(function() {
    $("#if").contents().on("mouseover", "p", function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Also see the [example for delegate()](http://jsfiddle.net/JVwFQ/2/) or [example for on()](http://jsfiddle.net/JVwFQ/1/): after the "mouseevent loaded" alert hover the cloud image.

P.s.: this will target all `<p>` within the iframe. But the iframe will only parsed if it is not a violation of the browser's cross-site policy.

Comment: If you use jQuery 1.7.2 replace the `live` with the `on` method (I've updated my answer).